# Capitalise and ignore comma

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def reverse (word):
    newword = ''
    letterflag = -1
    for numletter in word:
        newword += word[letterflag]
        letterflag-=1
        s=newword
    s.upper()
    return newword
  
def isPalindrome(word, ignorecase=False):

    """
    >>> type(isPalindrome("bob"))
    <type 'bool'>
    >>> isPalindrome("abc")
    False
    >>> isPalindrome("bob")
    True
    >>> isPalindrome("a man a plan a canal, panama")
        True
    >>> isPalindrome("A man a plan a canal, Panama")
    False
    >>> isPalindrome("A man a plan a canal, Panama", ignorecase=True)
    True
    """
    word = str (word)
    newword = reverse(word)
    if word == newword:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

When I type "Bob", I want it to return true because of the capital B.

Comment: FYI, you can reverse anything list-like with `thing[::-1]` (literally means: give me `thing`, starting at the first index, ending at the last index, and iterating by taking one step backwards each time). Or `reversed(thing)`.

Comment: FWIW, Python slice notation can reverse your word in one line `newword = word[::-1]`

Comment: -1 to the downvoters.  This question is clear and answerable.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I think part of the reason for downvotes is that this is a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your input always lower case that way you can avoid that problem altogether.

```
word = str(word)
word = word.lower()
word = word.replace(',', '') # removes any commas from the string
newword = word[::-1] # reverse string
if word == newword:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: and where i have to put that? at the end?

Comment: you dont need a reverse function. `'Hello'[::-1]` will reverse the string to 'olleH'

Comment: sorry my friend. thank you for your help but these are my first steps inn programming and i don't understand many things(sorry). i want this program to pass the doctest...in order that i should ignore capital leters and comma. can y please tell me how to do it? THANK YOU A LOT BY THE WAY

Comment: see updated answer. It converts the string to all lower case then removes any comma in the string.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn what is being done in this answer is to try individual parts of it in the Python console.

To fix your reverse() do this:

```
def reverse (word):
    newword = ''
    letterflag = -1
    for numletter in word:
        newword += word[letterflag]
        letterflag-=1
    return newword
```

Notice I also took out the .upper() parts since they are not effective and reverse is not the correct place to have it since you can not compare a reversed upper case word with the original word.  Also `s.upper()` does not work like you think it does.  It returns an upper case copy of `s` without modifying `s`.  You would only to do `return newword.upper()` to make it work.

Additionally, the letterflag is not needed, you could simply do:

```
def reverse (word):
    newword = ''
    for letter in word:
        newword = letter + newword #adds each new letter to beginning
    return newword
```

However the simplest way to do a reverse functions is:

```
def reverse (word):
    return word[::-1]
```

Your isPalendrome needs to be this to basically work:

```
def isPalindrome(word, ignorecase=False):
    word = word.replace(',', '').replace(' ', '') #removes ,'s and spaces
    if ignorecase:
        return word.lower() == reverse(word).lower()
    else:
        return word == reverse(word)
```

Here is a more advanced solution that will ignore anything that is not a letter with an option to ignore case.  This version does need reverse.

```
def isPalindrome(word, ignorecase=False):
    abcs = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    word = [c for c in word.lower()*ignorecase or word if c in abcs]
    return word == word[::-1] #no need for reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the option to be case sensitive, or the option to be case insensitive, add an IF statement in the isPalindrome() function:

```
if ignorecase == True:
    word = word.lower()
```

---

It should look like this when you are done:

```
import string
def reverse (word):
    newword = ''
    letterflag = -1
    for numletter in word:
        newword += word[letterflag]
        letterflag-=1
        s=newword
    s.upper()
    return newword

def isPalindrome(word, ignorecase=False):

    """
    >>> type(isPalindrome("bob"))
    <type 'bool'>
    >>> isPalindrome("abc")
    False
    >>> isPalindrome("bob")
    True
    >>> isPalindrome("a man a plan a canal, panama")
        True
    >>> isPalindrome("A man a plan a canal, Panama")
    False
    >>> isPalindrome("A man a plan a canal, Panama", ignorecase=True)
    True
    """
    if ignorecase == True:
        word = word.lower()
    word = word.replace(',', '')
    word = word.replace(' ', '')
    newword = reverse(word)
    if word == newword:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

That code gives me the following feedback:

```
isPalindrome('Bob', ignorecase=True)
Out[34]: True

isPalindrome('Bob')
Out[35]: False
```